# How do I reference a specific object based on its attribute, while it is in a loop, in Python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object, oop

I have a undirected circular graph of nodes, where the graph is made from a `Graph` class, and the nodes are made from a `Node` class. Each node has a few attributes, one of them being the `pos` attribute. In the Graph class, I have initialized a `graph` attribute which is a defaultdict. The `graph` is meant to have nodes of the Node class, with each node pointing to its next and previous nodes based on `pos`. If the node is 1, its previous node is the last node (let us consider it to have a `pos` value of 20), and vice versa for the last node. For now I have set each key of `graph` to have a value of `None`, but I want to set the value as the neighbors, to indicate edges. Here is what I have done so far:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.graph=defaultdict(Node)
        for i in range(1,21):
            self.graph[Node(i, False, False, False)]=None

    def edge_gen(self):
        for node in self.graph.keys():
            if node.pos==1:
                x=node
                continue
            if node.pos==50:
                self.graph[node.pos].add(x)
                self.graph[x].add(node.pos)
            prev_node=self.graph.keys()[node.pos-1] # Here is where I am lost
            print(prev_node, node)
            self.graph[node.pos].add(prev_node)
            self.graph[prev_node].add(node.pos)
        return self.graph
```

As indicated by the comment, at that step, I don't understand how to get the object of the neighbor node of the current node based on `pos`. I first tried to set `prev_node` as `node.pos-1` but I am aware that that won't work. I am putting the keys of `graph` in a loop, and for each node, I want to add its previous node as a value, and the same for the previous node and the current node. Can someone please help me understand how to get the previous node in this loop to form the edges and therefore create a circular undirected graph? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary for `self.graph`? Use a list, then `pos` is just the list index.

Comment: You think you are lost where you marked it, but ... you can't use `.add(...)` on a None value, so you are lost elsewhere. It seems that you don't  understand what you have created self.graph for. I suggest you rethink the entire logic and rewrite your code from scratch after you get clear understanding about what you want to achieve. Your code is mixing Nodes and integer values as self.graph keys what appears not to make much sense ...

Comment: You write: *For now I have set each key of graph to have a value of None* . This is not true. You set each key of graph to have a Node as value and the value of graph[key] to None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How do I reference a specific object based on its attribute, while it is in a loop, in Python?*

If the object in a loop is delivered by an iterator you have in a loop code block access only to this one object. So the answer to your question above is: *You can't reference a specific object based on its attribute while looping over an objects delivering iterator.*

Having this question answered, my best guess about what you actually want to achieve with the code you provided is as follows:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, pos, v1, v2, v3):
        self.pos = pos
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
        self.v3 = v3

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, noOfNodes) -> None:
        assert noOfNodes > 2
        self.graph = {}
        self.graph[1] = [ 
            Node(noOfNodes  , False, False, False), 
            Node(    2      , False, False, False), ]
        for i in range(2, noOfNodes):
            self.graph[i] = [ 
            Node( i-1, False, False, False), 
            Node( i+1, False, False, False), ]
        self.graph[noOfNodes] = [ 
            Node(noOfNodes-1, False, False, False), 
            Node(    1      , False, False, False), ]

    def edge_gen(self):
        return self.graph

g = Graph(3)
print(g.edge_gen())
```

or

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, pos, v1, v2, v3):
        self.pos = pos
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
        self.v3 = v3

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, noOfNodes) -> None:
        assert noOfNodes > 2
        self.noOfNodes = noOfNodes
        self.listOfNodes = [None] # index 0 won't be used  
        for i in range(1, noOfNodes+1):
            self.listOfNodes.append(Node(i , False, False, False))
        self.graph = dict(zip(self.listOfNodes[1:], [None]*noOfNodes))

    def edge_gen(self):
        self.graph[self.listOfNodes[1]] = [ 
            self.listOfNodes[self.noOfNodes], 
            self.listOfNodes[      2       ] ]
        for i in range(2, self.noOfNodes):
            self.graph[self.listOfNodes[i]] = [ 
                self.listOfNodes[i-1], 
                self.listOfNodes[i+1] ]
        self.graph[self.listOfNodes[self.noOfNodes]] = [ 
            self.listOfNodes[self.noOfNodes-1], 
            self.listOfNodes[      1         ] ]
        return self.graph

g = Graph(3)
print(g.graph)
print(g.edge_gen())
```

Hope this helps to get you off the dead end road of looking for a solution in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while understanding classes and objects in theory, this is my first time actually trying to implement it in code.